# Extract values from two XML files and do math

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have two XML files that are updated every 60 seconds. I need to extract the FormattedValue in DI-2 from scrap yds and the FormattedValue in DI-2 from total yds. Then I need to divide the value from scrap yds by the value in total yds. For example, User 1 has 48.3 yards in scrap and 1454.1 yards in total. So 48.3 / 1454.1 = 0.033 or 3.3%. I need to do this for each of the 13 users.

Then I need to display the percentage for each User / Machine on a webpage. I know HTML and CSS pretty well, but I have no idea how to go about processing the XML files. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is an example of total yds XML file

```
    <Report xmlns="http://www.barcovision.com/schemas/sns/export-basic" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema-instance" xml:space="preserve">
  <Stylesheet xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <Section Type="Header">
    <Row>
      <Cell ColumnHead="KI-30">
        <Value xsi:type="xsi:string">Inspector Name</Value></Cell>
    <Cell ColumnHead="KI-26">
      <Value xsi:type="xsi:string">Frame</Value></Cell>
    <Cell ColumnHead="DI-2">
      <Value xsi:type="xsi:string">Length (yd)</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 1     </FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">User 1     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>1454.1</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">1454.09998</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 1     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 1     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>1454.1</FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="double">1454.09998</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 2     </FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">User 2     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>709.8</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">709.8</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 2     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 2     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>709.8</FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="double">709.8</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 3     </FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">User 3     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>612.2</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double"612.2</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 3     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 3     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>612.2</FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="double">612.2</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 4     </FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">User 4     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>2269.3</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">2269.3</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 4     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 4     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>2269.3</FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="double">2269.3</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 5     </FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">User 5     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>200.0</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">200.0</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 5     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 5     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>200.0</FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="double">200.0</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 6     </FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">User 6     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>1442.8</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">1442.8</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 6     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 6     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>1442.8</FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="double">1442.8</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 7     </FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">User 7     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>3007.0</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">3007.0</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 7     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 7     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>3007.0</FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="double">3007.0</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 8     </FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">User 8     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>1140.8</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">1140.8</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 8     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 8     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>1140.8</FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="double">1140.8</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 9     </FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">User 9     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>604.3</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">604.3</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 9     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 9     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>604.3</FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="double">604.3</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 10     </FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">User 10     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>1638.2</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">1638.2</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 10     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 10     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>1638.2</FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="double">1638.2</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 11     </FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">User 11     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>211.8</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">211.8</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 11     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 11     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>211.8</FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="double">211.8</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 12     </FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">User 12     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>1787.8</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">1787.8</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 12     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 12     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>1787.8</FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="double">1787.8</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 13     </FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">User 13     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>709.8</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">709.8</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 13     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 13     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>709.8</FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="double">709.8</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
<Section Type="Total">
  <Row>
    <Cell Column="KI-30">
      <FormattedValue>Grand Total: 13     </FormattedValue>
<Value xsi:type="string">Grand Total: 13     </Value></Cell>
<Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue/>
<Value xsi:type="string"/></Cell>
<Cell Column="DI-2">
  <FormattedValue>18265.2</FormattedValue>
<Value xsi:type="double">18265.19976</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Stylesheet></Report>
```

This is an example of scrap yds XML file

```
<Report xmlns="http://www.barcovision.com/schemas/sns/export-basic" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema-instance" xml:space="preserve">
  <Stylesheet xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <Section Type="Header">
    <Row>
      <Cell ColumnHead="KI-30">
        <Value xsi:type="xsi:string">Inspector Name</Value></Cell>
      <Cell ColumnHead="KI-26"><Value xsi:type="xsi:string">Frame</Value></Cell>
    <Cell ColumnHead="DI-2"><Value xsi:type="xsi:string">Length (yd)</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 1     </FormattedValue>
    <Value xsi:type="string">User 1     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26">
          <FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2">
          <FormattedValue>48.3</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="double">48.29999</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 1     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 1     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2">
        <FormattedValue>48.3</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">48.29999</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 2     </FormattedValue>
    <Value xsi:type="string">User 2     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26">
          <FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2">
          <FormattedValue>25.6</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="double">25.6</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 2     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 2     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2">
        <FormattedValue>25.6</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">25.6</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 3     </FormattedValue>
    <Value xsi:type="string">User 3     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26">
          <FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2">
          <FormattedValue>27.2</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="double">27.2</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 3     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 3     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2">
        <FormattedValue>27.2</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">27.2</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 4     </FormattedValue>
    <Value xsi:type="string">User 4     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26">
          <FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2">
          <FormattedValue>3.7</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="double">3.7</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 4     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 4     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2">
        <FormattedValue>3.7</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">3.7</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 5     </FormattedValue>
    <Value xsi:type="string">User 5     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26">
          <FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2">
          <FormattedValue>56.7</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="double">56.7</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 5     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 5     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2">
        <FormattedValue>56.7</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">56.7</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 6     </FormattedValue>
    <Value xsi:type="string">User 6     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26">
          <FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2">
          <FormattedValue>33.1</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="double">33.1</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 6     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 6     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2">
        <FormattedValue>33.1</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">33.1</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 7     </FormattedValue>
    <Value xsi:type="string">User 7     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26">
          <FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2">
          <FormattedValue>161.5</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="double">161.5</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 7     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 7     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2">
        <FormattedValue>161.5</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">161.5</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 8     </FormattedValue>
    <Value xsi:type="string">User 8     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26">
          <FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2">
          <FormattedValue>62.3</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="double">62.3</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 8     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 8     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2">
        <FormattedValue>62.3</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">62.3</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 9     </FormattedValue>
    <Value xsi:type="string">User 9     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26">
          <FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2">
          <FormattedValue>23.3</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="double">23.3</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 9     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 9     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2">
        <FormattedValue>23.3</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">23.3</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 10     </FormattedValue>
    <Value xsi:type="string">User 10     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26">
          <FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2">
          <FormattedValue>73.0</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="double">73.0</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 10     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 10     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2">
        <FormattedValue>73.0</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">73.0</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 11     </FormattedValue>
    <Value xsi:type="string">User 11     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26">
          <FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2">
          <FormattedValue>5.6</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="double">5.6</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 11     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 11     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2">
        <FormattedValue>5.6</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">5.6</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 12     </FormattedValue>
    <Value xsi:type="string">User 12     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26">
          <FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2">
          <FormattedValue>11.0</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="double">11.0</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 12     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 12     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2">
        <FormattedValue>11.0</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">11.0</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
  <Section Type="Group">
    <Section Type="Details">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>User 13     </FormattedValue>
    <Value xsi:type="string">User 13     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26">
          <FormattedValue>M007</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">M007</Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2">
          <FormattedValue>48.3</FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="double">48.29999</Value></Cell></Row></Section>

  <Section Type="Total">
    <Row>
      <Cell Column="KI-30">
        <FormattedValue>User 13     </FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="string">User 13     </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue>1   </FormattedValue>
      <Value xsi:type="string">1   </Value></Cell>
      <Cell Column="DI-2">
        <FormattedValue>48.3</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">48.29999</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Section>
    <Section Type="Total">
      <Row>
        <Cell Column="KI-30">
          <FormattedValue>Grand Total: 12     </FormattedValue>
          <Value xsi:type="string">Grand Total: 12     </Value></Cell>
        <Cell Column="KI-26"><FormattedValue/>
        <Value xsi:type="string"/></Cell>
        <Cell Column="DI-2"><FormattedValue>531.3</FormattedValue>
        <Value xsi:type="double">531.29988</Value></Cell></Row></Section></Stylesheet></Report>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read from 2 XML files, then actually:

- the first XML file loads the XSL file (and it processes the XML),
- this XSL file, among other things, loads the second XML file and makes use of it.

The basic idea is that XSL file:

- loops through `Group` sections (in the 1st XML file),
- from the current section it reads `Row` tag contained in (embedded) `Total` section,
- from this row it reads `User Name` and `Total value`,
- reads `Scrap value` from the second file (lookup using the current user name),
- computes the ratio,
- generates a table row.

For the purpose of my tests I made the following changes to your files:

- I removed `Stylesheet` tag from both files.
- I removed `xmlns=".../export-basic"` namespace.
- I added `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Report_1.xsl"?>` to the first
  file, just before the `Report` tag (`Report_1.xsl` is my XSL file,
  see below).

And here you have a working example of XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:variable name="rep_2" select="document('Report_2.xml')" />
  <xsl:variable name="rep2Totals" select=
    "$rep_2/Report/Section[@Type='Group']/Section[@Type='Total']"/>

  <xsl:template match="Report">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 100px">User Name</th>
        <th style="width: 60px">Scrap Value</th>
        <th style="width: 75px">Total Value</th>
        <th style="width: 75px">Ratio</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Section[@Type='Group']">
        <xsl:variable name="totalRow" select="Section[@Type='Total']/Row"/>
        <xsl:variable name="userName" select=
          "$totalRow/Cell[@Column='KI-30']/FormattedValue"/>
        <xsl:variable name="totalVal" select=
          "$totalRow/Cell[@Column='DI-2']/FormattedValue"/>
        <xsl:variable name="rep2Row" select=
          "$rep2Totals/Row/Cell[@Column='KI-30'][FormattedValue=$userName]/.."/>
        <xsl:variable name="scrapVal" select=
          "$rep2Row/Cell[@Column='DI-2']/FormattedValue"/>
        <xsl:variable name="divRes" select=
          "format-number($scrapVal div $totalVal, '##0.00%')"/>
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($userName)"/></td>
          <td class="right"><xsl:value-of select="$scrapVal"/></td>
          <td class="right"><xsl:value-of select="$totalVal"/></td>
          <td class="right"><xsl:value-of select="$divRes"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <hmtl>
      <head>
        <title>Report</title>
        <style>
        td { padding: 2px 6px; }
        .right { text-align: right; padding-right: 12px; }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </hmtl>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())]"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

All 3 files: *Report_1.xml* (total data), *Report_2.xml* (scrap data),
and *Report_1.xsl* (the above transformation) should be in the same directory.
In a browser you open the first XML file.

I tested them using Firefox.

Comment: That's perfect Valdi_Bo! This is a huge help!